# How to handle color of progress bar value in JSS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jss

I am creating a progress bar component using Typescript & JSS in react.

My component extends:

```
React.ProgressHTMLAttributes<Element>
```

I am able to create the progress bar component. However, I am not able to handle the value color in JSS.

Image available at the link.

In CSS,

We use the following code:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background: green;
}
```

This works correctly in CSS. However, I am not aware of how to use it in JSS.

I have tried the following: -

```
progress: {
        webkit: {
        value: {
          backgroundColor: "green"
        } }
      },
```

If the type of the component is passed as success, then the color should change to green. If the type of component is passed as error, then the color should change to red. 
Thus, I have a wrapper of 'success' in my JSS file.

```
success: {
     /* progress::-webkit-progress-value {
        background-color: green;
      }*/

      progress: {
        webkit: {
        value: {
          backgroundColor: "green"
        } }
      },
      /*'&:progress': {
        '&:webkit.value': {
          backgroundColor: 'green'
        },
      }*/
      //color: "green",
      //progress.value.backgroundColor: ""
      //webkit.progress.value.backgroundColor: "green"
      //progress.value.color: "green"
      //HTMLProgressElement.progress.webkit.value = 
    },
```

which is called when the user has selected Type as Green.

```
[`${classes!.success}`]: type === ProgressIndicatorType.Success
```

If the type of the component is passed as success, then the color should change to green. If the type of component is passed as error, then the color should change to red.

Comment: Adding a link to a jss playground with the code for progress bar - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jss-playground-k09ye?fontsize=14

Comment: One can edit code of "color" in the styles class in order to play with the color of the progress value - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jss-playground-k09ye?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are applying the success className directly to the progress element, you will need the following JSS:

```
success: {
  '-webkit-appearance'       : 'none',
  'appearance'               : 'none',
  '&::-webkit-progress-value': {
    'backgroundColor': 'green',
  },
}
```

Here is explained why you need to reset the appearance.

https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/#article-header-id-4

Answer (score 2):

in JSS, pseudo-elements are prefixed with an ampersand.

```
'&::-webkit-progress-value': {
    background: green;
}'
```